# shared interactive scales with 1D or tick plot

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

When a plot is either 1D or has tick marks, the domain is forced to include to origin. When I combine this plot with another 2D/non-tick plot, shared interactive scales don't work.

```py
domain = alt.selection_interval(bind="scales", encodings=["x", "y"])

chart_1d =\
    ( alt.Chart(d1d)
    . mark_tick()
    . encode(x="values")
    . add_selection(domain)
    )

chart_2d =\
    ( alt.Chart(d2d)
    . mark_line()
    . encode(x="x", y="y")
    . add_selection(domain)
    )

chart = alt.vconcat(chart_1d, chart_2d)
```

I would like:

- The domain of the 1D chart to use the domain of the 2D chart, whatever that may be.
- Panning in the x-axis and zooming to be shared.
- Panning in the y-axis to be disabled only for the 1D chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to make this happen is to use the same field name for both x axes:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

d1d = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
d2d = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [2, 3, 2, 3]})

domain = alt.selection_interval(bind="scales", encodings=["x", "y"])

chart_1d =\
    ( alt.Chart(d1d)
    . mark_tick()
    . encode(alt.X("x", title='values'))
    . add_selection(domain)
    )

chart_2d =\
    ( alt.Chart(d2d)
    . mark_line()
    . encode(x="x", y="y")
    . add_selection(domain)
    )

chart = alt.vconcat(chart_1d, chart_2d)
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense but the origin issue is still present. For example, `d1d += 100; d2d += 100`. Then the first chart has a domain of [0,110] while the second [100,104] *until* the selection is activated. My guess is that you're going to recommend I set a starting domain as a workaround. What is the default vega/vega-lite domain, i.e. data +- 5%?

Comment: See the documentation for [altair.Scale.zero](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Scale.html). See for [altair.Scale.nice](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Scale.html) if you're having trouble setting the domain.

Comment: @jakedvp: I have to say I'm not understanding `nice` as an integer. Given `d2d + 1000`, `domain=[-10, 1500]` and only `chart_2d`, `nice=0|1 == nice=False` (ticks unchanged, tick gap 50, domain as specified) but `nice=2` sets domain to [-2000,2000] with a tick gap of 100, `nice=3|4` sets domain to [-500,1500] with a tick gap of 50, `nice=5` sets domain to [-500,2000] with a tick gap of 100, etc...